# Gradient Descend for Quadratic Function with Non Negative Constraints with Constant Step Size

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I have a minimization problem with quadratic objective and non-negativity constraints:
$$
\min_u\frac{1}{2}||a-u||^2+\frac{\gamma}{2}||B^Tu-x||^2+\lambda\sum_iu_i\\
\text{s.t } u_i\ge0
$$
where $\lambda$ a scalar, $a,x$ are vectors, $B$ a matrix, and $u_i$ the $i$th coordinate of $u$. I am doing a single iteration of projected-gradient algorithm, with 
$$
\text{grad} f=u-a+\gamma B(B^Tu-x)+\lambda
$$
where $\lambda$ is now a vector of all coordinates equal to the scalar $\lambda$ (sorry for the abuse of notation). The Lipschitz constant of the gradient is easily calculated to be 
$$
L=||I+\gamma BB^T||_2=1+\gamma\sigma_{\text{max}}^2(B)
$$
where the matrix norm is the spectral norm (largest singular value, or $\sigma_{\text{max}}$). All this enables me to choose an optimal step size of $\frac{1}{L}$, which ensures (among other things) that the objective is non-decreasing after the projected gradient step - the projection in my case is simply zeroing the negative coordinates of $u$ after the gradient step.

My problem is that when I apply this step to real data, the objective sometimes grows, which doesn't make sense. Do I have a mistake in the above derivation?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean $ L = 1 + \gamma \sigma_{\text{max}}^2(B)$ ?
Is your PG scheme the following $u^{(k+1)} \leftarrow \left(u^{(k)} - (1/L)\text{grad}f (u^{(k)})\right)_+$ ?

Comment: Yes to both questions (forgot the $\gamma$, thanks)

Comment: You derivations above seem correct to me. I'd advice to check for bugs in your code. Such a scheme is provably monotone.

Comment: @ItamarKatz, Could you share a specific $ \boldsymbol{B}, \boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x} $ which yields issue for you?

Comment: @Royi, that question is > 6 years old, so sorry I don't have the details any more.

Comment: @ItamarKatz. since there is no access to the data which causes issues I wrote the generic solution (You already know) with a margin guideline.

Answer (score 2):

If the function is given by:

$$ f \left( \boldsymbol{u} \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{a} - \boldsymbol{u} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\gamma}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{B}^{T} \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda \sum_{i} {u}_{i} $$

Then the gradient is given by:

$$ \nabla_{f} \left( \boldsymbol{u} \right) = \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{a} + \gamma \boldsymbol{B} \left( \boldsymbol{B}^{T} \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{x} \right) + \lambda \boldsymbol{1} $$

The projection over the set:

$$ \mathcal{C} = \left\{ \boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid {y}_{i} \geq 0 \; \forall i \in \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \right\} \right\} \implies \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \boldsymbol{u} \right) = \max \left( \boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{0} \right) $$

The solution by Projected Gradient Descent:

> - Set / Initialize: $\boldsymbol{u}_{0}, N, \eta$.
> - For $i \in \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, N \right\}$
>
>   - $ \boldsymbol{u}_{i} = \boldsymbol{u}_{i - 1} - \eta \nabla_{f} \left( \boldsymbol{u}_{i - 1} \right) $.
>   - $ \boldsymbol{u}_{i} =  \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \boldsymbol{u}_{i} \right)$.

Where $ \eta \leq \frac{1}{L} = \frac{1}{1 + \gamma {\sigma}^{2}} $ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of the function and $\sigma$ is the largest singular value of $\boldsymbol{B}$.

Since we're dealing with floating point arithmetic, we need to have some margin from $\frac{1}{L}$, then it should converge.

[image]

The Julia code is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q2230545 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `Mathematics\Q2230545` folder).